# CDI not working in objects created from factory pattern implementation

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, websphere-liberty

I am trying to wrap my head around something here: Injection only **works on the first layer** of my application, but then it stops and **all @Inject annotated properties are null** in the objects returned from my factory pattern implementation. I read a lot about people having problems with getting CDI to work with JAX-RS but this seems not to be my problem. I have the feeling that I am missing some annotations, or I don't see the wood in front of all the trees (as we say here) ;-)

*Edit: Did a sample project with the code I posted here to double check. Now I realise that I over simplified:  in fact I am using a **Factory Pattern** to obtain my service, which might interrupt the managed context. Please see the augmented example:*

Let's go.

First Layer: JAX-RS Application, **all good**

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/somePath/someResource")
public class SomeResource {
   @Inject
   ISomeServiceFactory someServiceFactory;

   @POST
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public SomeResponse someMethod(@PathParam("foo") final String foo) {
      ISomeService myService = someServiceFactory.getService(ServiceCatalog.valueOf(foo));   // works, we jump in there!
      myService.someMethod();
   }

}

public enum ServiceCatalog {
  STANDARD("standard"), ADVANCED("advanced"), FOO("foo");
  // ...
}
```

The **broken** service factory that is selecting an implementation based of known parameter (Enum) values from the REST API Call:

```
public interface ISomeServiceFactory {
  public ISomeService getService(ServiceCatalog serviceType);
} 

@Stateless
public class SomeServiceFactory implements ISomeServiceFactory {
  public ISomeService getService(ServiceCatalog serviceType) {
    if(serviceType.equals(ServiceCatalog.FOO)) {
      return new FooService();  // will break CDI context
    } else if (...) {
      // ...
    } else {
      return new DefaultService(); // will also break CDI context
    }
  }
}
```

Second Layer: Some EJB, **trouble here**

```
// Interface: 

public interface ISomeService {
  public void someMethod();
}

// Implementation:

@Stateless
public class SomeService implements ISomeService {
  @Inject
  private ISomeDao someDao;    // this will be null !!!

  @Override
  public void someMethod() {
    someDao.doSomething()   // exception thrown as someDao == null
  }
}
```

The Dao that is supposed to be injected

```
public interface ISomeDao {
  public void someMethod();
}

@Stateless
public class SomeDao implements ISomeDao {
  public void someMethod() {}
}
```

Now at runtime WebSphere Liberty tells me (among other bindings...) this:

```
 com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime
 I CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ISomeDao interface of the
 SomeDao enterprise bean in the my.war module of the my application.  
 The binding location is: java:global/my/SomeDao!com.ISomeDao
```

I have a beans.xml:

```
 <beans
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all">
 </beans>
```

It seems as if the new SomeService() breaks everything, could you advice on how to implement the factory in a way that enables CDI further down the road? Thanks.

Comment: In case this is relevant, I am running on the WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.8, with the following feature set installed: [servlet-3.1, jndi-1.0, jaxrs-2.0, cdi-1.2, webProfile-7.0, ejbLite-3.2, ejbHome-3.2, ejbRemote-3.2, javaee-7.0, ejb-3.2, ...] and have javaee-api 7, cdi-api 1.2, javax.inject 1 in my maven pom.xml

Comment: the feature list is definetely relevant -- I'd reccomend updating your question with at least the `<featureManager>` portion of your server.xml

Comment: As requested: `<featureManager><feature>javaee-7.0</feature><feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature><feature>localConnector-1.0</feature><feature>cdi-1.2</feature><feature>jsonp-1.0</feature></featureManager>`

Comment: What I meant to say is that if you explained a bit what you were trying to accomplish in your factory, then the question would be how to use CDI to do that (in place of trying to new up instances yourself).  Won't try to guess though since you're obviously abstracting out a simplified version of what you're doing.    By the time you do this and formulate your new question, you might be able to just do a new search without waiting for a new answer on this thread.  Good luck.

Comment: I will add some detail about this in the question Scott.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the amended question, you show that there is not actually an EJB injected into the web service, it is new'ed up indirectly via the factory.

An object only has CDI injection performed into it when the container creates the object, either by itself being injected somewhere or it being one of the managed EE components.

Net, you can't new-up an EJB or any CDI bean and have any CDI services in it.

Comment: Yes you are right, that's what I figured too. I am reading now how to get the factory up and running within CDI constraints. I would need to have something with @Produce that returns an implementation based on an Enum Value. Curious on how to implement this the most elegant way. Until then thanks for your input.

Comment: I don't think we know from this questions context what kind of choice you're trying to make by not just injecting the EJB by type.  But the next easiest is type + qualifiers.

Comment: Yes you need a producer class that can produce instances of your class.
here is the example: http://buraktas.com/cdi-dependency-injection-producer-method-example